# Can multiple function compositions be differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If i have $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and i know $f\circ f$ is differentiable then does that mean that $f\circ f\circ f$ is differentiable ?

I can't tell if i need to counter this or prove.
And if i have to counter then what kind of counter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No : take $f$ to be an involution (i.e. $f\circ f(x)=x$) that is not differentiable. An example of such a function is

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $x=-1$} \\
-1 &\text{if $x=1$} \\
x &\text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}.
$$

Notice how this function is not even continuous.

Comment: but it is given that $f$º$f$ is differentiable

Comment: I personally like to split between $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto -x$ depending on whether $x$ is rational. But a counterexample is a counterexample.

Comment: @Nicole Have you seen what $f\circ f$ is in this case? It is indeed a very differentiable function.

Comment: i dont understand how you decided that its equal to x , sorry for the ignorance

Answer (score 0):

No. Take for example the function: 
$${f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x} &\text{if } x \neq 0  \\
0 &\text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}}$$

The function $f \circ f$ is continuous and differentiable , but $f \circ f\circ f$ isn't.